# SUM by Combination in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I want to get from this table:

```
  [ProductCode] [ClientNO] [Fund]
     11            3         100
     12            4          45
     11            3          18
     12            4           5
```

To this one:

```
[ProductCode] [ClientNO] [Fund]
     11            3        118
     12            4         50
```

So basically sum `FUND` when all the given variables match.

I'm almost there with this statement:

```
 Proc sql;
        create table SumByCombination as
        select *, sum(Fund) as Total
        from FundsData
        group by ProductCode,ClientNO
        ;
     quit;
```

But with this I get all the rows (duplicates) with a SUM column.

Edit: This is what I get.

```
  [ProductCode] [ClientNO] [_SUM_]
     11            3         118
     12            4          50
     11            3         118
     12            4          50
```

I know this should be a no-brainer but I keep getting stuck. 
What would be the easiest way to do this in Proc SQL ? What about other methods ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using `SELECT *` in your queries. You should explicitly identify the columns that you want the SELECT to return.

Select * is nasty and evil and should very very rarely, if ever, be used.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59861/1), which returns your expected result

```
select  ProductCode
        ,ClientNO
        ,sum(Fund) as Total
from    FundsData
group by 
        ProductCode
        ,ClientNO
```

Comment: That would only drop the `Fund` variable but I would still get the third table from above while I'm trying to get the second one (without duplicates).

Comment: What Third table? There is only one table in use! Have a look at the sql Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59861/1 and you will see that this query is returning what you asked for.

Comment: You're right, the problem was that I was trying to keep another variable(not in the example) that wasn't grouped by so it basically forced all the rows to stick around, same problem as with the `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using SAS, so do it the SAS way - PROC MEANS.

```
proc means data=fundsdata;
var fund;
class productcode clientno;
types productcode*clientno;
output out=sumbycombination sum(fund)=fund;
run;
```